# countdown time data not showing in every loop card in JavaScript php mysqli

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I have created a card and want to show time countdown for every row for same table and the loop is working well but timer just working for 1st loop and then it's not working for others loop not showing time countdown.

1st loop is fine like ...

> 100$ Package Plan
> 2.50$ Daily Earning time : 19h13m15s

but the second loop is showing without time like ..

> 25$ Package Plan
> 0.63$ Daily Earning time :

the time countdown need to show for every loop fetched data by the interval_time column. Need help .

Here is my php code
`

```
    foreach($getActivePackages as $data){
    $status= $data['status'];
    $pack_term=$data['pack_term'];
    $packId =$data['id'];
    $interval_time =$data['interval_time'];
    $splitTimeStamp = explode(" ",$interval_time);
    $date = $splitTimeStamp[0];
    $time = $splitTimeStamp[1];
    $getPackageTerm = $getData->specificItem('pack', 'id', $pack_term);
    foreach($getPackageTerm as $row){
    $amount= $row['amount'];
    $days   =$row['days'];
    $interest = $row['daily_percentage'];
    $withdrawamount = ($amount*$interest)/100;
    $totalWithdraw = $withdrawamount+$amount;
    $dailyAmount = $totalWithdraw/$days ;
    $dailyAmount =number_format($dailyAmount, 2);
    }
    $data = strtotime($date);
    $getDate = date(" Y, F, d", $data);
```

`

HTML
`

```
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-12 col-xl-4 text-center text-xl-right">
    <p class="font-weight-normal" id="counter"></p>
    </div>
```

`

JS

`

```
    <script>
    var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo "$getDate $time"; ?>").getTime();
    var x = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownDate - now; // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML =hours +"Hours" + minutes + " min " + seconds + "s ";
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
    }, 1000);
    </script>
    <?php } ?>
```

`

tried to loop the document.getElementById("counter") also put the JS inside the loop but the result is same loop data is retrieving but time is not showing in every single looped data.

Answer (score -1):

The problem arises because you're reusing the same JavaScript variable names for each iteration of the loop, causing conflicts between the timers. You can solve this by dynamically generating unique IDs for each timer and corresponding elements.

Here's an updated version of code that should work for displaying separate countdown timers for each row in the table:

```
    <?php
foreach($getActivePackages as $data){
    $status= $data['status'];
    $pack_term=$data['pack_term'];
    $packId =$data['id'];
    $interval_time =$data['interval_time'];
    $splitTimeStamp = explode(" ",$interval_time);
    $date = $splitTimeStamp[0];
    $time = $splitTimeStamp[1];
    $getPackageTerm = $getData->specificItem('pack', 'id', $pack_term);
    foreach($getPackageTerm as $row){
        $amount= $row['amount'];
        $days   =$row['days'];
        $interest = $row['daily_percentage'];
        $withdrawamount = ($amount*$interest)/100;
        $totalWithdraw = $withdrawamount+$amount;
        $dailyAmount = $totalWithdraw/$days ;
        $dailyAmount =number_format($dailyAmount, 2);
    }
    $countDownDate = strtotime($date . ' ' . $time); // Move this line inside the outer loop
    $counterId = "counter_" . $packId; // Generate a unique ID for each timer
    $formattedDate = date(" Y, F, d", $countDownDate);
    echo '<div id="' . $counterId . '">' . $formattedDate . '</div>';
}
?>

<script>
<?php
foreach($getActivePackages as $data){
    $packId =$data['id'];
    $counterId = "counter_" . $packId;
    echo 'var countDownDate_' . $packId . ' = new Date("' . $formattedDate . '").getTime();';
    echo 'var x_' . $packId . ' = setInterval(function() {';
    echo 'var now = new Date().getTime();';
    echo 'var distance = countDownDate_' . $packId . ' - now;';
    echo 'var hours = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60));';
    echo 'var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));';
    echo 'var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);';
    echo 'document.getElementById("' . $counterId . '").innerHTML = hours + " Hours " + minutes + " min " + seconds + "s ";';
    echo 'if (distance < 0) {';
    echo 'clearInterval(x_' . $packId . ');';
    echo 'document.getElementById("' . $counterId . '").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";';
    echo '}';
    echo '}, 1000);';
}
?>
</script>
```